# Simple location.href with php echo in in link

Tags: php, echo, href

I have pretty straight forward question:

What would be the correct syntax for this be?

```
onclick="location.href = '/xxx/xxx?key='.'<? $value[0]->pass_key; ?>'"
```

At the moment, this redirect's to my page `/xxx/xxx/?key`, but leaves out my pass_key, which i need to generate data on the resulting page.

**UPDATE**

Was a mistake not to use

```
    <?= ?>
```

which is the same as

```
   <? echo ?>
```

I've updated it in my code still no key is passed along.

This statement resides in this tag:

```
   <td>
```

**SOLVED**

Thx to *chinnu* and y'all!

And what's up with the downvote? :( just because it's a simple mistake/question. .

Prudes.

Comment: You're not `echo`ing that value

Comment: Always use the full php tag, shorthand isn't recommended `<?php ?>` and you need to echo out the value so it shows, `<?php echo $value[0]->pass_key; ?>`

Comment: `<?php echo ...` or `<?= ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  onclick="location.href = '/xxx/xxx?key=<?php echo $value[0]->pass_key; ?>'"
```

Comment: I have tested this with like $key=md5(time()); onclick="location.href = '/xxx/xxx?key=<?php echo $key; ?>'"

Comment: Ty Chinnu. I've found my mistake, i was retriving value from a wrong result array. really appreciate the quick response! <3